# How to create a collapsable grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a grid in this website:

http://projetistamotorsporttop5.com/teste-css/

The grid contains the icons and text beside them, just below the sign up button.

I wanted to implement this through a grid, so that I could place the text below the title and both beside the icon, so it set of icon, title and text make a "unit". Here's how I went on to implement it:

```
.grid-container {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    max-width: 70vw;
    padding-top: 8vh;
    padding-bottom: 0vh;
}
.grid-container > div {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.item-1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
.item-2 {
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rajdhani';
    font-size: 175%;
}
.item-3 {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
}
.item-4 {
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    grid-column: 5 / 7;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rajdhani';
    font-size: 175%;
}
.item-5 {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 7 / 8;
}
.item-6 {
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    grid-column: 8 / 10;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rajdhani';
    font-size: 175%;
}
.item-7 {
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rajdhani';
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
.item-8 {
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
    grid-column: 5 / 7;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rajdhani';
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
.item-9 {
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
    grid-column: 8 / 10;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rajdhani';
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
.laranja {
    background: #f79510;
    display: inline;
}

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item-1"><img src="lock.png" width=80></div>
    <div class="item-2">100% Safe purchase</div>
    <div class="item-7">Your data are protected and your purchase is safe.</div>
    <div class="item-3"><img src="Lightining.png" width=80></div>
    <div class="item-4">Imediate access</div>
    <div class="item-8">All lectures available upon enrollment confirmation.</div>
    <div class="item-5"><img src="Garantia.png" width=160></div>
    <div class="item-6">15 day warranty</div>
    <div class="item-9">You can ask for a full refund during this period.</div>
</div>
```

It works just fine when I view it in full screen, as in a laptop, but I want it to be responsive, so that when user resizes screen or views the page on a smartphone, the "units (icon + title + text)" are shown below each other, instead of side by side. The way I implemented this, it shows as an horizontal table, which doesn't collapse on smaller screens.

The titles are the ones in class items 2, 4 and 6, while the texts are the ones on class items 7, 8 and 9. Any ideas on how to implement it? I have tried to change the display property of the class `.grid-container`, but had no success.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all the styles that are not relevant to the solution.

I have used an aditional class to simulate the mobile view. Of course, you should handle this using media queries , or similar.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 2fr;
  max-width: 70vw;
  padding-top: 8vh;
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.grid-container>div {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.item-7 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.item-8 {
  grid-column: 4;
}

.item-9 {
  grid-column: 6;
}

.grid-container.mobile {
   width: 250px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.mobile .item-1, .mobile .item-3, .mobile .item-5 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.mobile .item-8 {
  grid-column: unset;
}

.mobile .item-9 {
  grid-column: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item-1">lock.png</div>
  <div class="item-2">100% Safe purchase</div>
  <div class="item-7">Your data are protected and your purchase is safe.</div>
  <div class="item-3">Lightining.png</div>
  <div class="item-4">Imediate access</div>
  <div class="item-8">All lectures available upon enrollment confirmation.</div>
  <div class="item-5">Garantia.png</div>
  <div class="item-6">15 day warranty</div>
  <div class="item-9">You can ask for a full refund during this period.</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container mobile">
  <div class="item-1">lock.png</div>
  <div class="item-2">100% Safe purchase</div>
  <div class="item-7">Your data are protected and your purchase is safe.</div>
  <div class="item-3">Lightining.png</div>
  <div class="item-4">Imediate access</div>
  <div class="item-8">All lectures available upon enrollment confirmation.</div>
  <div class="item-5">Garantia.png</div>
  <div class="item-6">15 day warranty</div>
  <div class="item-9">You can ask for a full refund during this period.</div>
</div>
```